# How does Excel compare strings using less than and greater than?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel it is possible to do comparisons between non-numeric cells with `<` and `>`. Any string is handled as greater than any numeric input, such as `="string">1000` evaluating to `TRUE`. Additionally `TRUE`and `FALSE` are evaluated as greater than any string or numeric input. For instance, both `=FALSE>"string"` and `TRUE>"string"` evaluate as `TRUE`.

This also works for comparing two strings, which appears to be connected to character codes, but I can't figure out exactly how. For instance, `="bbb">"aab"` and `="bbb">"bab"` both evaluate to `TRUE`, but `="bbb">"aaf"` evaluates to `TRUE`  while `="bbb">"faf"` evaluates to `FALSE`. Initially I thought that each character's code was being compared, but the last formula seems to suggest that this is incorrect.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand what calculations are happening here. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that is using the alphabet... b comes after a, so `b>a` even thought `aaaaa`could seem greater than `b`, `b` stills comes after `a`. Look at it af it were car plates,  `A1000` is older than `B0001` so older means lower and newer means bigger. At least this is what I get from the tests.

Comment: Are you actually trying to accomplish something here?  There are better ways to compare strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done following alphabetic ordering, you can see this by putting all mentioned strings within one column and sort that column Z->A, you'll end up with following order:

```
faf
bbb
bab
aaf
aab
```

Which corresponds to your findings.

Comment: Thank you! The other question you linked was helpful.